# matching cyrilic characters with kotlins Regex.kt

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am not able to match cyrillic strings in kotlin doing the following:

```
val regex = Regex(":\\p{Cyrillic}*:")
regex.find(any)
```

IDE shows word Cyrillic red and compiler says:

```
Unknown character property name {Cyrillic} near index 27
```

How to do this properly with kotlin?

Comment: whats wrong with this question. Please comment when downrating. Otherwise downrating doesn't make sence.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `In` prefix, `\p{InCyrillic}`:

```
val regex = Regex(":\\p{InCyrillic}*:")
println(regex.findAll(":Привет:...:Пока:").map{it.value}.joinToString() )
// => :Привет:, :Пока:
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/QIMuUv)